# MS Access SQL Union Query Order By Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of dates in a table (datatype=text) that I would like to pull down in ascending order from a combobox using a query as part of a filter on a form. I would also like to add an "All" into the list so the user can reset the filter using the combobox.

I can get the dates in order and I can union the "All" option but I can't get the two to work together. Can anyone help?

This gets the dates in order:

```
SELECT TESTTABLE.DateTest
FROM TESTTABLE
ORDER BY CDate(TESTTABLE.DateTest);
```

This does the union but leaves the dates in the wrong order:

```
SELECT TESTTABLE.DateTest
FROM TESTTABLE
UNION SELECT "(All)" AS BOGUS FROM TESTTABLE
```

I'd love to combine the two options into one query to put the "All" at the top of the list of returned values from the query with the dates in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Format** function to sort the dates stored as text. `(All)` will be at top as special character have lowest value and then the letters

```
Select * from (
SELECT DISTINCT TESTTABLE.DateTest
FROM TESTTABLE
UNION SELECT "(All)" AS BOGUS FROM TESTTABLE)
order by Format(DateTest,'yyyy-mm-dd') asc
```

Comment: @digitrac Great, pls click on checkmark to mark this as answered

Comment: Just tried to put the solution on the real application and realized I omitted to say that the date query uses distinct to prevent loads of repeated dates appearing in the filter list:

Comment: When I try the above answer with distinct I get the following error:

Comment: 'Only those fields requested in the first query can be included in an ORDER BY expression

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using a dummay column for order by

```
select * from
(
SELECT TESTTABLE.DateTest,2 as ord
FROM TESTTABLE
UNION SELECT "(All)" AS BOGUS,1 FROM TESTTABLE
)A order by ord,CDate(DateTest)
```

Comment: HI - Thanks for the answer but this also leaves the dates in the wrong order

Comment: Hi - Sorry the dates are still un-ordered

Comment: could you please add sample data to your question @digitrac

Comment: DateTest
(All)
03/07/2017
05/04/2019
06/03/2016
08/01/2018
10/01/2017

Comment: @digitrac, though i modify it a bit, but this query definitely return your desired result if your date field is ok

Comment: This query returns a data mismatch error in criteria expression

Comment: Can confirm that this _doesn't_ work in Access 2010; haven't got other versions available today - I was surprised too

Comment: Yes this is Access 2010

Comment: This can't work because the row with `"(All)"` will also run through `CDate()`.